# tkinter collecting checkboxes into a list

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.configure(background="white")
c_list = []
my_list = []
def get_value():
    for c in c_list:
        my_list.append(c.get())
    root.destroy()
MAIN_CATEGORIES = ['Arts & Crafts', 'Automotive', 'Baby', 'Beauty & Personal Care', 'Books',
 'Computers', 'Digital Music', 'Electronics', 'Kindle Store', 'Prime Video', "Women's Fashion",]
for i in range(1,len(MAIN_CATEGORIES)):
    exec(f'c{i}=tk.BooleanVar()')
    c_list.append(f'c{i}')
for ind,i in enumerate(MAIN_CATEGORIES):
    temp = tk.Checkbutton(root,text=i,variable=f'c{ind+1}',anchor="w",bg='grey',)
    temp.grid(row=ind, column=2, sticky='W')
tk.Button(root,text='Get Category',command=lambda: get_value,bg="grey").grid(row=ind+1, column=3, sticky='W')
root.mainloop()
print(my_list)
```

Hello, I am trying to collect the boxes checked in `my_list` right now I am not getting any boxes in output (when I `print(my_list)`). I.e I want to collect all boxes checked into `my_list` and then destroy the `root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should almost never use `exec` in this way. It makes code hard to read, and provides no real benefit over using a dictionary or list.

So, to create the variables you could do something like this:

```
vars = {}
for category in MAIN_CATEGORIES:
    vars[category] = tk.BooleanVar()
```

You then can use these in your checkbuttons like so:

```
for row, category in enumerate(MAIN_CATEGORIES):
    temp = tk.Checkbutton(..., variable=vars[category], ...)     
    temp.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky='W')
```

For `get_values`, you can just iterate over the categories:

```
def get_value():
    for (category, var) in vars.items():
        print(f"{category}={var.get()}")
        my_list.append(var.get())
    root.destroy()
```

Finally, you need to have your button call `get_value` properly. You don't need to use lambda:

```
tk.Button(..., command=get_value..).grid(...)
```